# SwiftUI Picker with EmptyView still presents empty space

Tags: swiftui

I have a `Picker` within a `Form`. I don't want to show any label on this `Picker`, so I set the label to `EmptyView()`. Though, the UI still presents an empty space where the label would be. I'm looking for a way to remove this space.

[image]

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form {
...                
                Section(header: Text("Emails")){
                    HStack{
                        Picker(selection: $phoneType, label: EmptyView()){
                            ForEach(phoneTypes, id: \.self){
                                Text($0)
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
                        Spacer()
                        Link("my@email.com", destination: URL(string: "mailto:my@email.com")!)
                    }
                    Button("Add Email") {}
                }
...   
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("John Doe")
    }
```

Comment: Which version of iOS are you using?

Comment: @darshilsakhiya 16.2

Comment: @LudovicC You need to add the `navigationTitle` view modifier to your `Form`, not on `NavigationView`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach is to use [`labelsHidden()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/labelshidden()) to hide the label of `Picker`.

```
Picker(selection: $phoneType, label: EmptyView()){
    ForEach(phoneTypes, id: \.self){
        Text($0)
    }
}
.labelsHidden()
.pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is using Picker inside Menu:

```
                    HStack{
                        Menu {
                            Picker("", selection: $phoneType){
                                ForEach(["Work","Home","Cell"], id: \.self){ type in
                                    Button(type) { phoneType = type }
                                }
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Text(phoneType).foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                        Link("my@email.com", destination: URL(string: "mailto:my@email.com")!)
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the Text in the loop inside an HStack and add a trailing Spacer

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        Form {
...                
            Section(header: Text("Emails")){
                HStack{
                    Picker(selection: $phoneType, label: EmptyView()){
                        ForEach(phoneTypes, id: \.self){ t in
                            HStack {
                                Text(t)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
                    Spacer()
                    Link("my@email.com", destination: URL(string: "mailto:my@email.com")!)
                }
                Button("Add Email") {}
            }
...   
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("John Doe")
}
```